# I want to know if i can add two different custom post types to my wordpress site

Tags: custom-post-types

I'm trying to add two custom post types, "articles" and "projects". Using a php code i found on wpbeginner, "articles" post has worked. But when I'm trying the same code with "projects" i'm getting a code error.

> Your PHP code changes were rolled back due to an error on line 70 of
> file wp-content/themes/generatepress-child/functions.php. Please fix
> and try saving again.
>
> Cannot redeclare create_posttype() (previously declared in
> wp-content/themes/generatepress-child/functions.php:34)

```
    // Our custom post type function
function create_posttype() {
 
    register_post_type( 'articles',
    // CPT Options
        array(
            'labels' => array(
                'name' => __( 'Articles' ),
                'singular_name' => __( 'Article' )
            ),
            'public' => true,
            'has_archive' => true,
            'rewrite' => array('slug' => 'articles'),
            'show_in_rest' => true,
 
        )
    );
}
// Hooking up our function to theme setup
add_action( 'init', 'create_posttype' );


// Our custom post type function
function create_posttype() {
 
    register_post_type( 'projects',
    // CPT Options
        array(
            'labels' => array(
                'name' => __( 'Projects' ),
                'singular_name' => __( 'Project' )
            ),
            'public' => true,
            'has_archive' => true,
            'rewrite' => array('slug' => 'projects'),
            'show_in_rest' => true,
 
        )
    );
}
// Hooking up our function to theme setup
add_action( 'init', 'create_posttype' );
```

Comment: You can't re-use function names. You need to use something other than `create_posttype()` for the second function. Or better yet just register them both in one function.

Answer (score 1):

As [Jacob Peattie](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/users/39152/jacob-peattie) pointed out [in this comment](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/371390/i-want-to-know-if-i-can-add-two-different-custom-post-types-to-my-wordpress-site#comment539037_371390), the reason why you code isn't working is because you have two functions with same name `create_posttype`. PHP assumes you want to re-declare the function, which you cannot do.

So in order for your code to work, you can either combine your custom post types creation into one function (as Jacob suggests):

```php
    // Our custom post type function
function create_posttype() {
 
    register_post_type( 'articles',
    // CPT Options
        array(
            'labels' => array(
                'name' => __( 'Articles' ),
                'singular_name' => __( 'Article' )
            ),
            'public' => true,
            'has_archive' => true,
            'rewrite' => array('slug' => 'articles'),
            'show_in_rest' => true,
 
        )
    );

    register_post_type( 'projects',
    // CPT Options
        array(
            'labels' => array(
                'name' => __( 'Projects' ),
                'singular_name' => __( 'Project' )
            ),
            'public' => true,
            'has_archive' => true,
            'rewrite' => array('slug' => 'projects'),
            'show_in_rest' => true,
 
        )
    );
}
// Hooking up our function to theme setup
add_action( 'init', 'create_posttype' );
```

... or give each function an unique name if you prefer to use two functions:

```php
    // Our custom post type function
function create_posttype_articles() {
 
    register_post_type( 'articles',
    // CPT Options
        array(
            'labels' => array(
                'name' => __( 'Articles' ),
                'singular_name' => __( 'Article' )
            ),
            'public' => true,
            'has_archive' => true,
            'rewrite' => array('slug' => 'articles'),
            'show_in_rest' => true,
 
        )
    );
}
// Hooking up our function to theme setup
add_action( 'init', 'create_posttype_articles' );


// Our custom post type function
function create_posttype_projects() {
 
    register_post_type( 'projects',
    // CPT Options
        array(
            'labels' => array(
                'name' => __( 'Projects' ),
                'singular_name' => __( 'Project' )
            ),
            'public' => true,
            'has_archive' => true,
            'rewrite' => array('slug' => 'projects'),
            'show_in_rest' => true,
 
        )
    );
}
// Hooking up our function to theme setup
add_action( 'init', 'create_posttype_projects' );
```